# #include file with path based on variable .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to include a file in my .aspx document where part of the file path is based on a variable collected from a function.

I have tried this:

```
<!-- #include virtual="/<%=MyClass.GetDirectory() %>/include/pageFooter.aspx" -->
```

But get the error:
Parser Error Message: Illegal characters in path.

I guess you can not use code with include file/virtual. Is there an equivalent of this so I can get it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you like to do that? What are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

My first question is why are you trying to include an aspx? Why not use a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.aspx)?

However, assuming there's some other reason I tend to do this sort of thing with a literal control.

```
<asp:Literal ID="IncludeLiteral" runat="server" />
```

Then in your code behind

```
this.IncludeLiteral.Text = string.Concat(MyClass.GetDirectory(), @"/include/pageFooter.aspx");
```

Comment: Then it's more likely pageFooter.html, not pageFooter.aspx

Comment: @zespri, yeah - so it's probably more appropriate to use a Master page or a control